# how can i free database that include dataset and linked_data

Tags: c

I want to know how can I free the database .I mean I have to free the linked_data and then dataset and then database or I can free it just by use free for address of database

Comment: Take bottom up approach. Start by freeing the _innermost_ pointer first. Otherwise, it'll be a memory leak.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's consider an example.

```
char ** cPointer = NULL;
```

Now, we'll allocate memory in a way

```
cPointer = malloc(5 * sizeof (*cPointer ));   ------> (1)
for (i = 0; i < 5; i ++)
   cPointer[i] = malloc(32);                  -------> (2)
```

here, in case (1), we're allocating memory to `cPointer`

Similarly, in case (2), we're allocating memory to `cPointer[i]`

Now, you can notice, the pointer returned by `malloc()` in case (2) is stored in the pointer returned by `malloc()` in case (1).

So, if you free up the `cPointer` first, before freeing up the `cPointer[i]`s, then you'll have no way to access the `cPointer[i]`s and thus, you cannot `free()` the dynamically allocated memory for `cPointer[i]`s. That will lead you to memory leak.

So, the solution is, first `free()` the *inner* pointer(s) `cPointer[i]`s, then `free()` the *outer*`cPointer` itself.